# How to give empty conditions in controller of cakephp 3.2 during model bind?

Tags: php, cakephp, bind, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.2

I am new to cakephp 3.
Below is my code.

```html
  $getFlags = $this->Posts->find('all')->contain(['Users', 'Flags.Users', 'Flags.FlagReasons', 'Flags.Users.Schools']);
```

output

```html
{
        "id": 114,
        "title": "",
         "allow_comment": 0,
        "owner_id": 84,
        "created": "2016-04-08T04:41:08+0000",
        "status": 1,
        "flags": [],
        "user": {
            "id": 84,
             "profile_image": "bc7484cd8caad0de055f8d7ef15551f5.png",
            "is_active": 1
        }
```

Here i want to give a condition,when there is an empty flag ,it will not be listed in result.
Only post having flag will come.
Please suggest me.
ANy suggstion will highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get this done:

- Use a [counter cache](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/counter-cache.html) and filter by that field (flag_count > 0)
- Do a [subquery](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#subqueries) to get the count (inefficient)